# Changing keypad type in Embarcadero Delphi Stringgrid

Tags: android, delphi, android-keypad

To those who are familiarized with programming Android apps in Embarcadero XE7 or 8, I have a question.

When adding a TEdit component to my app, I have the option to change the keyboard type in the object inspector. However, I need to change the keyboard type of a Stringgrid also, but its object inspector does not have that option. What do I do? Is there a code that does that?

Regards,

Reis

Comment: Without being too fluent in FMX, I can advise that using an overlay control on top of the grid is one way to go. I did this plenty in VCL, but haven't gotten that far in FMX just yet.